# Get PSK of incorrect WPA-PSK attempts

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, hostapd

I was using hostapd to create an AP. I have some knowledge of C++. I was wondering if I can use hostapd to get the incorrect PSK entered by the client, or get that information from anywhere else. If necessary I can modify the source code of hostapd.

Comment: Why do people keep downvoting questions just because the answer is "no"?

Answer (score 3):

Nope.

It would be a really terrible security protocol if you could, because then anyone could set up a rogue AP and learn the PSK of the network they want to attack.